# Min-cost-max-flow with signum in objective function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, heuristics, nonlinear-optimization, max-flow

I have some kind of Min-cost-max-flow  problem with simple balance equations in constraints, but with "bad" signum in objective function,
i.e., the objective function depends only on the existence of the flow along the edge, not on its value.

[image]

I can introduce bool variable `U_i` constrained `U_i <= x_i` and
rewrite objective function with `U_i`, but it is mixed integer programming model. In my real data, the number of variables must be at least `10000`
and the number of rows of constraints is also about `10000`.

Q1: Is it too slow to use simple branch and cut method?

Q2: Are there any tricks to solve this problem with preserving model linearity? (I think answer is not)

Q3: So, Are there any effective approaches for solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

1. Usually the constraint for the binaries looks like

   `x(i) <= y(i)*capacity(i)`

   for arc `i` where `x(i)` is flow and `y(i) ∈ {0,1}`. This models the implication

   `y(i)=0 => x(i)=0`
2. Many (but not all) models with a network structure can be solved quickly even after adding integer restrictions. You really just should try it out (which is the best answer for most questions about performance). Easy models with 10k binary variables are not automatically out of range. Use a good MIP solver.